# Sharepoint 2010 DeleteExpiredSessions job is registered for the database

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, sharepoint-2010

I am running SharePoint 2010.  I keep getting "Expired sessions are not being deleted from the ASP.NET Session State database." warnings.

I connect to the server that hosts the ASP.NET Session State database, I start the SQL Server Agent service, and I confirm that a DeleteExpiredSessions job is registered for the database. I execute the stored procedure and a couple minutes later the warning is gone.

I come back the next day and I have the warning again.  My question is there must be a way to automate this execution right? Either directly in SQL Server Management Studio or SharePoint Central Administration.  I can't seem to find out how though.

Answer (score 0):

You can re-create the "State Service Delete Expired Sessions" job definition by disable and re-enable the ASP.Net State Service via powershell, also you should verify that your account has the appropriate permissions in order to allow it to create SQL Agent jobs.

```
Disable-SPSessionStateService
Enable-SPSessionStateService –DefaultProvision
```

[Here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/briangre/archive/2013/09/09/expired-sessions-are-not-being-deleted-from-the-asp-net-session-state-database.aspx) you can read a little more about this fix.